# Firefox: Jquery AJAX request fails when using file:/// url

Tags: ajax, firefox, file-uri

I have an ajax request created in JQuery.

- when run from a file:/// url, it succeeds in all browswers (EXCEPT firefox)...

However, when saving the same html page in s3, and accessing it from s3,

- it works in all browswers (INCLUDING firefox) !

**My question**

Why would the file:/// declaration cause firefox to not open an html page correctly... could it be due to character encodings or the default way that browsers process file:/// URIs ?